# JPopupMenu not closing on keyevent

Tags: java, swing

I have two internal frames in a JFrame. One has a popup in it and the other opens on a keyboard event.
The problem I have is that the JPopupMenu not being dismisses unless I click out side of it. Please refer the code below.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createAndShowUI();
                } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() throws PropertyVetoException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test Frame");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

        JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane();
        TestInternalFrameWPopup testInternalFrame1 = new TestInternalFrameWPopup();
        pane.add(testInternalFrame1);

        testInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(pane);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        testInternalFrame1.setMaximum(true);
        frame.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction(e -> {
            TestInternalFrame testInternalFrame2 = new TestInternalFrame();
            pane.add(testInternalFrame2);
            try {
                testInternalFrame2.setMaximum(true);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            testInternalFrame2.setVisible(true);

        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_U, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK), JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

/**
 * Background color Cyan
 */
class TestInternalFrameWPopup extends JInternalFrame {

    TestInternalFrameWPopup() {
        jbInit();
    }

    private void jbInit() {
        setTitle("Test Internal Frame With Popup");
        setContentPane(getContainerPanel());
        setMaximizable(true);
        setClosable(true);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        setSize(500, 300);
    }

    private JPanel getContainerPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test Label");
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Item 2");
        JMenuItem menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Item 3");
        JMenuItem menuItem4 = new JMenuItem("Item 4");
        JMenuItem menuItem5 = new JMenuItem("Item 5");
        menuItem1.setOpaque(false);
        menuItem2.setOpaque(false);
        menuItem3.setOpaque(false);
        menuItem4.setOpaque(false);
        menuItem5.setOpaque(false);
        popup.add(menuItem1);
        popup.add(menuItem2);
        popup.add(menuItem3);
        popup.add(menuItem4);
        popup.add(menuItem5);
        label.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
        popup.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        panel.add(label, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        return panel;
    }
}

/**
 * Background color Gray
 *
 */
class TestInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    public TestInternalFrame() {
        jbInit();
    }

    private void jbInit() {
        setTitle("Test Internal Frame");
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setMaximizable(true);
        setClosable(true);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        setSize(500, 300);
    }
}
```

When I open the popup by clicking on Test Label on my first internal frame and press Ctrl+U in keyboard it results in a scenario where my popup is over a wrong internal frame.
Does anyone have come across something like this before?
Is there anyway around this without manually dismissing my pop on key event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected that the popup menu was more closely tied to the currently focused component, but in this case that doesn't seem to the be truth.  I did solve it by using a `InternalFrameListener` and monitor for the deactivated, iconified and closing the events and dismissing the keyboard then, but someone else might know a better solution

Comment: Reported an issue to Java regarding this and they have accepted and added it to their bug database. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8173739 Hopefully they will fix it soon.